# python print progress for nested for loop without using third party package

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print a download progress like "[1/5] > [2/5]", but my code will reset to 1 even it's done downloading the first image. How can I make the progress stay at specific number when it's downloading and increment number when it's done downloading the previous image?

This is my code :

```
            for image in images:
                list_of_links.append(image['src'] + '\n')
                img_id = 0
               
                # Saving the images in your computer

                for links in list_of_links:
                    image_url = links
                    ext = '.jpg'
                    img_id += 1
                    img_cid = str(img_id)
                    save_images = folder_path + '\\' + anime_name + img_cid + ext
                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, save_images)
                    print(f'[{img_id}/{how_many}] - Downloading...', end = '\r')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Progress resets to 1 is because of this img_id = 0 is inside the first for loop.

To Fix this move img_id = 0 before the first for Loop.

```
img_id = 0    
for image in images:
    list_of_links.append(image['src'] + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks sir ! i did not notice that simple mistake! Thanks a lot